# Select between given characters in vim

Tags: vim, vi

Given three sample lines:

```
some('lorem _ ipsum');
$some['lorem _ ipsum'];
<span class="some _ class">
```

(cursor is in `_` position)

Which is the fastest way to select (for pasting in other place):

- text between `'` quotes
- expand the selection to include the parenthesis
- text between parenthesis
- text between `<` and `>`

Answer (score 13):

`vi'` will select text between quotes (use `va'` to include the quotes themselves)

If you're already in visual mode, another `a(` or `ab` will expand to include the parentheses

`vi(` or `vib` will select text inside parentheses; `va(` or `vab` will select including the parentheses.

Similarly for `vi[`, `va[`, `vi<`, `va<`, etc.

See `:help text-objects` for more information.

Consider also skipping the selection step, and just yank (copy) them (`yi'`, `ya(`, etc.) or deleting (cutting) them (`da'`, `di<`, etc.) before pasting somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, any other options than *inside*? (as *inside* this does not work in IdeaVim (plugin for PHPStorm IDE) )

Comment: I don't know anything other than what it says at `:help text-objects`. I don't use that plugin, and would never even consider it if it interfered with such basic vim functionality.

Comment: And `ci` will change the text inside.